# Structure of the full symmetric group on a countably infinite set

Tags: group-theory, infinity, symmetric-groups

Trying to get a handle on the full symmetric group $S$ of permutations on a *countable* set $X$. I had never really thought much about this group, but now I look at it for the first time it appears a more complex idea than I had naively assumed. I will confine my expression of puzzlement to one fairly straightforward question, but any further input on this group would be much appreciated.

For any element $g \in S$ we have a disjoint decomposition:

$$
X= \sigma_g \cup \tau_g
$$
with
$$
\sigma_g \cap \tau_g = \emptyset
$$
where $\sigma_g$ is the set of points fixed by $g$

If $S_* = \{g \in S \mid \text{card}(\tau_g) \lt \aleph_0 \} $ then it seems that $S_*$ must be a normal subgroup of $S$.

(I have just noticed a comment by  [@ArturoMagidin](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/166358/normal-subgroups-of-infinite-symmetric-group) which makes me more confident to make this claim. However the discussion in that location does not single out countably infinite groups in particular, and is heavily dependent on some literature references that are quite obscure. I would just like a simple, commonsense explanation, if that is feasible.)

Can anyone help me improve my rather hazy conception of the factor group ${S}/{S_*}$ and its relation to $S^* =\{g \in S \mid \text{card}(\sigma_g) \lt \aleph_0 \} $?

Comment: Which comment are you referring to? See here for [How to quote and link in a comment](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10637/how-to-quote-and-link-in-a-comment) and references therein...

Comment: $S^*$ is of course far from being a subgroup

Comment: @draks ... thx 4 that tip, i will have a good look at it when time permits. but i'd like to have easy access to it.  i noticed recently in profile there is mention of favoriting questions as a way to save them for further reference, but i haven't yet discovered how one does this. cd you help me on that pls?

Comment: When you star/favor the meta post I mentioned, it should show up in your [meta accounts favorites](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users/79543/david-holden?tab=favorites), but the use of the favorites feature is in doubt when you favor a lot...

Comment: @Hagen yes i can see that, though not yet clearly. am also puzzled by an outwardly simple element like $(01)(23)(45)...$ on $\mathbb{N}$. one presumably cannot allow infinite products except under special circumstances. also i'm wondering if i was naive to talk about the symmetric group on a countable set, as it seems likely this type of group depends on some particular ordinal used to induce a well-ordering on the base set?

Comment: @draks when i did a site search on "favorite" all i got was a list of questions with this word in their title. so i still don't know what "button" to press to favorite something. your main point is noted.

Comment: Do you see the star below up/downvote?

Comment: @draks... that's another question i have. i see a line that says "share edit flag", but no reference to voting. i am pretty stupid, so have probably just missed it, but i have looked a few times. teething problems! thanks for your patience. could you tell me whereabouts the upvote/downvote button is to be found?

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this paper by [Alperin/Covington/Macpherson](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.11.6960) and references there in (seems to be free from citeseer). They analyze the automorophism group of your mystery quotient, which should tell you a fair bit about the structure.

Comment: that paper looks very relevant (though i'm less sure of my ability to comprehend it). unfortunately so far i have not been able to access the unzipped version. i will be seeing my brother in a few weeks, who is a computer whizz, so no doubt he will sort me out, as he did with mathjax recently, using which has been a wonderful experience for me, though i still have my L-plates on! there is no urgency, now the can of worms has been opened, i shall continue to gaze into it in mystified fascination for a while.

Comment: See this link: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s24/sh/7ee40acb-5eb7-448a-97ab-1bdfac7a3461/0ed2e311fb9d5bcc46f2c50a0bdf2f51

Comment: thank you, that is readable (well, let me not be over-ambitious, i'll say legible, for now) and it looks like the business on my untutored question.

Comment: I point out an error in the Alperin-Covington-MacPherson paper [here ("Near actions", ArXiv link)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.05065), yet the result on the automorphism group has been proved as correct and generalized by J. Truss.

Answer (score 4):

Just to clarify a few basic points.

The full symmetric group $S$ on a countably infinite set $X$ is indeed well-defined up to group isomorphism. (The same applies to sets $X$ with any given cardinality.)

$S_*$ is indeed a normal subgroup of $S$. It is easy to see that $g^{-1}hg \in S_*$ for all $g \in S$ and $h \in S_*$.

In fact it can be shown that $S$ has precisely four normal subgroups, $1$, $S$, $S_*$, and the the group $A_*$ of all even permutations in $S_*$. (Since the elements in $S_*$ move only finitely many points, they can be unambiguously defined as even or odd. But there is no meaningful way of attaching a parity to the elements of $S \setminus S_*$.) The group $A_*$ is simple.

I have no clear conception of the quotient group $S/S_*$ myself, so I cannot help you understand it intuitively! But it is a simple group.

Comment: thanks. the only idea i have about the quotient group, which is a very hand-waving thought, is that forming it must bear some (perhaps vague) analogy to the way the notion of a "germ" of differentiable function is defined. perhaps the notion of inverse limits in certain categories might furnish a more precise analogy, but i know only the barest outlines of category theory so far, so that doesn't help me much. auxiliary: it wd seem that an infinite series that is conditionally but not absolutely convergent is one whose sum is stable under $S_*$ but not under $S$ (acting on indices)?

Comment: PS i don't know as yet how to cast votes (or even if i am entitled to do so), but i would like to upvote your answer